# How can I erase background of UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitouch, eraser

I want to erase background of `UIImage` by using touch method. I try to erase background  but there are some problem to erase background.

Please any one know the answer of it please post here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

refer to this link -> http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-image-editing-component/637
hope you will get some idea

Comment: Thanks for giving answer. No, My solution is not there. Can you please give any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works well. But ***previousPoint2*** and ***currentPoint*** has some problems, you can change your previousPoint2's(or currentPoint) x or y. Also you can use method   `CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, float, float)`  to add some other lines to the path to find out how you can erase all the background image.

Or you can also change the ***width*** of the path, more than 25.0 points.So as a result, you will find other parts of the image are erased.Be happy to find out yourself.

Finally, you should understand the basic theory of Core Graphics.So, see the link bleow here:https://www.raywenderlich.com/33193/core-graphics-tutorial-arcs-and-paths. Apple's docs are always a better way to know about iOS&MacOX.

Comment: Thanks for giving answer... I try your solution but its not work for me. 
 I need erase background of image and create that eraser image with original size.